# Showing or hiding elements based on variables in controller - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-show, ng-hide

For all I know this might be more an AngularJS issue than an Ionic specific one. I have a button in one of my views:

```
<button class="button button-clear button-block button-positive" ui-sref="register">
    Register
 </button>
```

And in my controller I have this variable that I get from local storage that is either true or false and has to be hidden depending that the value is:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$localstorage',
  function($scope, $localstorage) {

  // Check if the user has already requested a register, and if true, hide
  // the 'Register' button
  if ($localstorage.get("registrationRequested", false) === true) {
    // How do I do this?
  }

}]);
```

Now the first question probably is, is it even a best practice to manipulate the dom like that from my controller? And if not, where and how do I do it? If its' fine doing it in my controller, then how do I reference that button and hide it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `ng-hide` directive to your button tag:

```
<button ng-hide=registered class="button button-clear button-block button-positive" ui-sref="register">
    Register
</button>
```

In your JS file, declare this value in your `$scope` to `false` and set it to `true` to hide the button:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$localstorage',
    function($scope, $localstorage) {
        $scope.registered = false;

        // Check if the user has already requested a register, and if true, hide
        // the 'Register' button
        if ($localstorage.get("registrationRequested", false) === true) {
            $scope.registered = true;
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Whoa! Thanks! As a quick question, is it safe to say that all the directives and features that are available in Angular is also available in Ionic? I'm kinda new to this as I'm sure you can tell..

Comment: Yes, that is safe to say.

Answer (score 3):

do as following :

```
<button class="button button-clear button-block button-positive" ui-sref="register" ng-show='showBtn'>
Register
```

in controller :

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$localstorage',
  function($scope, $localstorage) {
  if ($localstorage.get("registrationRequested", false) === true) {
     $scope.showBtn = true;
  }
  else{
     $scope.showBtn = false;
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `data-ng-hide` to hide or show. After setting it to `true` or `false` you have to apply the scope settings like this : 
`$scope.$apply();`

Answer (score -1):

you can use ng-if also to show the button as:

```
<button class="button button-bar button-positive" ng-if="resgisterBtn" ui-sref="register">Register</button>
```

in controller:

```
 app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$localstorage',
      function($scope, $localstorage) {
    if ($localstorage.get("registrationRequested", false) === true) {
         $scope.resgisterBtn = true;
      }
      else{
         $scope.resgisterBtn = false;
      }
    }]);
```

The difference between ng-show & ng-if is ng-show will keep the element alive in DOM but ng-if will do opposite